# MySQL (MariaDB) Not Starting '/usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete - mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.'

Tags: linux, database, service

I'm getting an error when i try to start mariadb.service service:

```
Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status mariadb.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

> systemctl status mariadb.service

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.5.15 database server
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sat 2022-04-09 16:24:54 CEST; 32s ago
   Docs: man:mariadbd(8)
         https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
Process: 8118 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -m 755 -o mysql -g root -d /var/run/mysqld (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 8119 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 8121 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ ! -e /usr/bin/galera_recovery ] && VAR= ||   VAR=`cd /usr/bin/..; /usr/bin/galera_recovery`; [ >
Process: 8135 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mariadbd $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER $_WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 8154 ExecStartPost=/bin/sh -c systemctl unset-environment _WSREP_START_POSITION (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 8156 ExecStartPost=/etc/mysql/debian-start (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

   Main PID: 8135 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Status: "MariaDB server is down"
        CPU: 305ms

Apr 09 16:24:53 raspberrypi mariadbd[8135]: 2022-04-09 16:24:53 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
Apr 09 16:24:53 raspberrypi mariadbd[8135]: 2022-04-09 16:24:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
Apr 09 16:24:53 raspberrypi mariadbd[8135]: 2022-04-09 16:24:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
Apr 09 16:24:53 raspberrypi mariadbd[8135]: 2022-04-09 16:24:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
Apr 09 16:24:53 raspberrypi mariadbd[8135]: 2022-04-09 16:24:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 220409 16:24:53
Apr 09 16:24:54 raspberrypi mariadbd[8135]: 2022-04-09 16:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
Apr 09 16:24:54 raspberrypi mariadbd[8135]: 2022-04-09 16:24:54 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 45238; transaction>
Apr 09 16:24:54 raspberrypi mariadbd[8135]: 2022-04-09 16:24:54 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: Shutdown complete
Apr 09 16:24:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 09 16:24:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.5.15 database server.
```

Comment: Is there any useful information in `/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log`? Does `journalctl -xe` add any more error messages?

Comment: @doneal24 There isn't a folder called mariadb in /var/log/.
[Here journalctl -xe](https://pastebin.com/yFW7zBky)

Comment: It says there in the `journalctl` output: `Apr 09 21:28:55 raspberrypi systemd[1578]: mariadb.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /etc/mysql/debian-start: No such file or directory`. You need to have that file and go from there.